# Field not found when searching in ILE C programs under debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, ibm-midrange

While I was working on an ILE C program under debug mode, I intended to search the occurrences of a field through the program. This field is part of a structure, so I included the structure variable name in the search as well. But the search did not always work. It displayed the message field not found occasionally, even if that variable was right in front of my eyes. And this happened again when I tried to use that field to set up a conditional breakpoint. Does anyone know why this happened? And how to solve this issue?

Comment: What debugger are you using?  How are you executing the search?  What is the scope of the variable/struc you are looking for?

Comment: I am using the ILE debugger using the F command to search the field. I want to search through the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the search in the ILE debugger using the F command, be sure to start at the top.  The ILE Debugger will search from the current point, or sometimes from the last search result.  Using T to go to the top of the source will reset that and then you can use F to find again from the top.

Comment: Then what about conditional breakpoint? Why did it report 'field not found' as well?

Comment: The 'F' command is a simple text search.  It doesn't know anything about the names of the variables - F will find the variable name even if it is inside a comment.  The conditional breakpoint will only work on variables found in the compiled program's symbol table.  This means that unreferenced variables can not be the subject of a conditional breakpoint, since they do not exist.  That's my guess.  Compile the program with OUTPUT(*PRINT) OPTION(*FULL) and check the cross references in the listing.  Does the variable show as referenced or unreferenced?

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking account of the fact that C is case-sensitive?  If you don't use the exact case of the variable name then the variable will not be found; certainly on the conditional breakpoint.